# Progress indicator not working on a table

Tags: list-manipulation, monitoring

Consider the following code

```
gammaList = Table[gamma, {gamma, 1, 10^8, 1}];

Monitor[Table[{gamma}, {gamma, gammaList}], 
 Row[{ProgressIndicator[gamma, {gammaList[[1]], gammaList[[-1]]}], 
   gamma}, " "]]
```

As you can see, there is no progressbar displaying and I don't understand why. For me everything is correct here

How to fix **in the most simple way** my problem ?

Comment: ``Table[{gamma}, {gamma, gammaList}]`` got auto-compiled so it's not being evaluated on the main loop (that'd be brutally slow anyway--keep as much off the main loop as possible). This means `Monitor` can't monitor it since it's happening squarely at the C/SIMD level. Try cutting `10^8` down to `10^2` and replacing `{gamma}` with `RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}]; {gamma}`. That's still a compilable expression but slow enough that you can see the indicator churn.

Comment: @b3m2a1 so just to understand: as my table is "simple" (not complicated own made function that I evaluate), the function is auto-compiled and then not possible to monitor it. If I had a different function to put in my table, then no auto-compiled version would exist and monitoring would be possible. Is that it ? Is there still a way to follow the process of the Table ?

Comment: Pretty much. Also because you have more than some threshold of elements (`250` I think but it's in `SystemOptions`). If your call were non-compilable (say using `FactorInteger`), yes, you'd be able to follow it, but you wouldn't want `Monitor` to be updating too often so it'd make sense to run it on some smaller `Table` with a coarser step-size (say by evaluating `1000` list elements in a chunk).

Comment: @b3m2a1 in conclusion, for an "auto compilable" expression that still takes time to be evaluated, is there a way to follow its progress ?

Comment: In my answer I show how to chunk a call so that you can watch it.

Answer (score 1):

To take some comments and put them into an answer, the reason this happens is auto-compilation. It's been extensively discussed on the site, but basically Mathematica will try to compile any call into `Table` that's large enough and with a simple enough function directly down to C before evaluating.

This means it's impervious to inspection by things like `Monitor` since it's not happening in the main evaluator loop. Consider this:

```
gammaList = Table[gamma, {gamma, 1, 10^2, 1}];
bigList = RandomReal[{}, {2000, 1000}];
Monitor[
  Table[
   bigList + gamma,
   {gamma, gammaList}], 
  Row[{ProgressIndicator[gamma, {gammaList[[1]], gammaList[[-1]]}], gamma}, 
   " "]
  ];
```

My old, slow computer can watch that churn. Now let's try bumping up the number of elements in `gammaList` and bumping down the `bigList` size:

```
gammaList = Table[gamma, {gamma, 1, 10^3, 1}];
bigList = RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}];
```

Now I just see this:

```
ProgressIndicator[gamma,{1,1000}]\[ThinSpace]gamma
```

Since `gamma` isn't in the main evaluator it can't be watched. A way around this is to use two calls into `Table`:

```
gammaList = Table[gamma, {gamma, 1, 10^3, 1}];
bigList = RandomReal[{}, {1000, 1000}];
chunkSize = 251;
numChunks = Ceiling[Length[gammaList]/chunkSize];
Monitor[
  Table[
   Table[
    bigList + gamma,
    {gamma, gammaList[[(chunk - 1)*chunkSize + 1 ;; UpTo[chunkSize*chunk]]]}
    ],
   {chunk, numChunks}
   ],
  Row[{ProgressIndicator[chunk, {1, numChunks}], chunk}, " "]
  ];
```

My computer complains vociferously about being asked to evaluate that, but you can watch it go.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to keep track of table iterators, I usually use, is:

```
Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[gamma/gammaMax]]
```

or

```
Dynamic[gamma]
```

Let us define the largest gamma value to be a bit smaller than `10^8` for the sake of example:

```
gammaMax=10^5;
```

Then, if you would like to actually see the increments being updated dynamically in the progress bar, you have to slow down the routine by, e.g., a `Pause` command:

```
gammaList = Table[Pause[0.00001]; gamma, {gamma, 1, gammaMax, 1}];
```

If you do not include a `Pause`, the `Table` is constructed so quickly, that the `Dynamic` routine has no chance to pick up on every individual step. Alternatively, if your actual `Table` components involve more complicated steps that naturally take a longer time to evaluate, then the `Pause` is not needed and you will be able to see increments dynamically as they come in.

As mentioned by [b3m2a1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208679/5517), if the function in each element of `Table` is too simple, Mathematica may compile the table and make the iterator not accessible to the main window. In such a case the routine again is likely to run so fast that monitoring the iterator may be pointless. In any case where the `Table` construction involves more complicated input that is not auto-compiled, the above `Dynamic` will work as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure how to make use of this Dynamic. Could you give a working example of what you suggest I'm a little bit confused (there is no display in your code).

Comment: @StarBucK Quite literally, place the `Dynamic` in a separate box and evaluate this box first. While `gammaMax` or `gamma` have no values, this will return the input. Once you start evaluating the `Table` in a later box, the previous output of `Dynamic` is then going to change dynamically. Make sure that you have 'Evaluation->Dynamic Updating Enabled' checked in the settings. Does this help?

Comment: `Monitor` is essentially doing just this. It could be mostly re-written as `myMonitor[a_, b_]:=(PrintTemporary[Dynamic[b]];a)`.